# maximum rows per group subset

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM user AS u 
JOIN article AS a
ON u.id = a.userid
GROUP BY u.id
```

How can I extract maximum 10 articles for each particular user?

Comment: http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/ may help

Answer (score 0):

Mysql don't have window functions for such type of results another work around is to use user defined variables to get the n result per group

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT a.*,
@r:= CASE WHEN @g = userid THEN @r + 1 ELSE 1 END row_num,
@g:= userid
FROM (SELECT * 
FROM `user` AS u 
JOIN article AS a
ON u.id = a.userid
ORDER BY u.id,a.id DESC
) a
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @g:=NULL,@r:0) b
) t
WHERE row_num <=10
```